# Cannot create Chart using Chart.JS @ 2.9.4

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart using Chart.JS (v2.9.4) but am unable to. Here is the relevant HTML

```
      <canvas
        id="groupPerformanceChart"
        class="lineClass"
        width="340"
        height="220"
        style="margin-top: 2px; height: 220px; width: 340px;"
      ></canvas>
```

and here is the relevant JS

```
  var ctx = $("#groupPerformanceChart");
  if (!ctx) {
    console.log("Context not available");
    return
  }
  else {
    console.log("Context available", ctx)
  }
  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: currLabels,
      datasets: dataSet,
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              max: 10,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

and here is what it says in the console:

```
Context available 
jQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: '#groupPerformanceChart'}

Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
```

Interestingly, the chart shows up sometimes if I trigger HMR in dev environment but obviously this won't work for production. I also have other charts in other places that are created the same way and work fine so this one has me stumped.

Comment: I have other charts that use the jQuery selector and they are working perfectly. I have also tried using ```document.getElementById("groupPerformanceChart")``` and ```document.getElementById("groupPerformanceChart").getContext('2d')``` and none of them are working in this case

Comment: Are you using Angular or React too? or just plain HTML/JS

Comment: This project is using MeteorJS

Comment: With an additional framework?

Comment: Nope just MeteorJS, I did ```npm i chart.js``` and it installed version 2.9.4 and all of my other charts are working perfectly

Comment: Oh this is inside of a Blaze template if that's relevant

Comment: I don't know how jQuery would behave in this scenario, because I have no experience with it, but it might be that the template isn't actually rendered / displayed in the exact moment you're getting the context and so Chart.js cannot get the canvas / the context

Comment: Yes I also thought of this so I have a ReactiveVar that makes the Chart function not run until the template is fully rendered and the proper data has been loaded. Since the jQuery is returning something in the console.log wouldn't this mean that it has been rendered/displayed?

Comment: As I said...I am not sure how jQuery would behave in this scenario, could you try logging what `getElementById` returns?

Comment: I just tested it in a playground, and jQuery always returns a non-null result, even if the searched object is not rendered / doesn't exist

Comment: Interesting, when I log ```document``` I can clearly see that the canvas element exists but when I do ```document.getElementById``` in the same place I get back null

Comment: Yes, this is because the document you log is still linked to the document, and so when you look at it the canvas will have already been placed inside

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you have the chart inside a template, which causes it not to be rendered in the moment that you are running the jQuery selector and constructing the chart.

jQuery will always return a value even if no objects have been found. So your check will always say that a context has been found. To fix this, you have to check the `length` of the jQuery result:

```js
var ctx = $("#groupPerformanceChart");
if (ctx.length <= 0) {
  console.log("Context not available");
  return;
}
else {
  console.log("Context available", ctx)
}
```

Comment: I see, this makes sense and it now says ```Context not available```. Any ideas for how to ensure the canvas has been rendered? Maybe putting the chart code in a timeout?

Comment: Maybe don't use a template, but use the visibility style instead...this will keep the canvas hidden, but make the element available. Or maybe in blaze there is a way to wait (or have an event listener) for a template rendering (but I don't know this...I never worked with blaze JS)

Comment: Interesting, I will try that. Thanks for the help!